# Removing Application Name from URLs in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have been trying to get a MVC3 application running on IIS 7 on Win Server 2008 R2 (64 bit)- and all is fine except that the application name has been appended to the URL.

www.xyz.com/apage -> www.xyz.com/myapp/apage

I have been trying to find a way to remove the application name.  I am not an expert by any means.  The pages I have found refer to either web.config rules, or a feature URL Rewrite (this doesnt work) as I can only find a 32 bit version which wont install.

Is this best done with routing tables in the MVC3 application (how to do it im not sure) or via web.config or via virtual directories config in IIS?

If anyone had a sample rule for web.config (that seems to be the most discussed approach) that would be great - the only sample i can find shows how to route to the same url which isnt much use.  Any resource or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so others learning this - i found out its the way the deployment works.

Easiest way if you only have a single site on the IIS server is to load it into the root applicaton.  This makes multiple sites a challenge, and will break under other circumstances.

In the deployment package, make sure the target site/applicaton is  set to "/"